# Multi-tenant users / roles persistance not accepting same names in different domains

Tags: java, security

I have tried to use OACC framework

> createResource("USER", "domain1","kim")

**USER** : resourceClass 
**domain1** : domain
**kim** : value to be stored (externalId)

*Sorry if arguments order are mismatched*

again I have called for :

> createResource("USER", "domain2","kim")

in this case, the system conflicts to store the same name , logically yes, externalId can't be same.

But how can we store the real values into this, a normal Resource instantiate will result in its own ID.

Is there any api to "getRoles" if I pass in a UserName ?

**A multi-tenant application will have (users/roles/permission) per domain, 1 user can exist in multiple domains !!**

Comment: since I don't have the required reputation I am not able to tag oacc. Appreciate if someone could edit and tag oacc.

Answer (score 1):

> But how can we store the real values into this, a normal Resource instantiate will result in its own ID.

As you noticed, the `createResource()` method can accept a `String externalId` parameter, which has to be a *globally unique string identifier* for the new resource. "Globally unique" here means unique across all domains and resource classes.
The `externalId` is useful to reference OACC resources by an identifier from your application domain, without having to use or store the unique `resourceId` OACC generates and returns from `createResource()`.

One way to use non-unique application domain identifiers as external IDs would be to prefix identifiers with an appropriate classifier to make them unique within OACC. Such a prefix could simply be composed of the resource class, domain, or both. To use your example:

```java
createResource("USER", "domain1", "user.domain1.kim");
createResource("USER", "domain2", "user.domain2.kim");
```

> Is there any api to "getRoles" if I pass in a UserName ?

In OACC you can *model* role assignment by having one resource "inherit" all permissions from another resource by granting it the `*INHERIT` permission. In other words, there is no *explicit* concept of roles within OACC and hence no dedicated method to "getRoles".

In any case, the best practice for authorizations is to **check against permissions**, not against role membership.

For auditing or administrative purposes, if you do need to find the resources a specific user inherits permissions from, OACC provides *query methods* such as `getResourcesByResourcePermissions()`. If, for example, all your "roles" were modeled as resources of the resource class `ROLE`, you could find the ones your user inherits with the following call:

```java
getResourcesByResourcePermissions(userResource, 
                                  "ROLE", 
                                  ResourcePermissions
                                    .getInstance(ResourcePermissions.INHERIT));
```